# texture doesn't interact with light

Tags: shaders, lighting

I'm new to blender and i tried to create a ghibli style shader. but this texture (on a plane) doesn't interact with the lighting (see screenshot).
shadow visibility is selected everywhere so i don't understand the problem.
Help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: what does it give if you put a Diffuse just before the Output?

Answer (score 3):

When you plug textures directly into the surface material output instead of a shader node, it is treated the same way as if you plugged it into an emission shader, which by nature is unaffected by surrounding light : it is a light.

You should add a shader node before the material output. May it be a Principled BSDF if you want 5o have all kinds of features like specular, or a simple Diffuse BSDF.